# Не правильно выполняеться автолог на PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

Мне нужно реализовать автологин в приложении. Данные пользователя у меня запоминаются. При проверке, если данные логина и пароля верны, нужно перейти на другой виджет (AboutTheProgram). Я сделал проверку в функции входа в систему, которая находится в модуле MainWindows. Но у меня получается, что открываются два окна вместо одного.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    maindow = MainWindows()
    maindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

MainWindows.py

```
class MainWindows(QDialog, Ui_ImageDialog):
    homeAction = None

    oldPos = QPoint()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.password = None
        self.offset = None
        self.username = None
        self.dragPos = None
        self.reg = None
        self.abouttheprogram = None
        MainWindows.id_Profile = 6
        self.MainMenu = Ui_ImageDialog
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('ZoomApp')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image/icon/logo.png'))


        RemoveWindowsMenu(self)#Убирает windows форму
        #БД
        self.client = client
        self.db = db
        self.coll = coll
        self.collLoggedIn = collLoggedIn
        #Запомнить пользователя
        self.settings = QSettings("ZoomIndistinct", 'AppWise')
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.settings.value("login", ""))
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(self.settings.value("password", ""))
        self.checkBox.setChecked(bool(self.settings.value("remember", "")))
        self.login()

        # Кнопки
        self.pushClose.clicked.connect(self.CloseWindow)  # При нажатии на кнопку login перейти на новую страницу
        self.pushUrlYouTube.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/'))
        self.pushUrlDiscord.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://discord.gg/JWTcSq3Y'))
        self.pushUrlFacebook.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://www.facebook.com/rrarrkfacit'))
        self.pushUrlGitHub.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('https://github.com/'))
        self.status = self.label_4
        self.status.setStyleSheet('font-size:10px; color: red;text-align: center;')
        self.pushReg.clicked.connect(self.WindowReg)



        #Перемещение окна UpBar
        self.UpBar.setStyleSheet("border-top-left-radius: 1px; ")
        self.UpBar.move(45, 35)
        self.UpBar.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and self.UpBar.underMouse():
            self.offset = event.pos()
        else:
            self.offset = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self.offset is not None and event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and self.UpBar.underMouse():
            self.move(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos() - self.offset))
        else:
            self.offset = None


    def login(self):
        self.username = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.password = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        result_pass = db.users.find_one({'firstname': self.username, 'password': self.password})
        self.id_Profile = result_pass['_id']  # запомнить id пользователя после логина
        if self.settings.contains("login") and self.settings.contains("password"):
            self.TransitionAboutTheProgram()
        else:
            pass




    @staticmethod
    def CloseWindow():
        sys.exit()



    def TransitionAboutTheProgram(self):
        self.hide()
        self.abouttheprogram = AboutTheProgram(self.id_Profile)
        self.abouttheprogram.show()



    def WindowReg(self):
        self.reg = Class.Registration.Refistration()
        self.reg.show()
        self.hide()
```

AbountTheProgram.py

```
class AboutTheProgram(QDialog, Ui_AboutTheProgram,Ui_ImageDialog):
    def __init__(self,id_Profile):
        super().__init__()

        self.offset = None
        self.oldPos = None
        self.ui = None
        self.logo_text = None
        self.abouttheprogram = Ui_AboutTheProgram
        self.setupUi(self)
        RemoveWindowsMenu(self)  # Убирает windows форму
        self.id_Profile = id_Profile
        print(self.id_Profile)

        self.importmainclass = main.MainWindows
        self.importregclass = main.Refistration
        self.nameUsers = os.getlogin()
        if os.path.isfile(f'/Users/{self.nameUsers}\Downloads/soft.txt'):
            os.remove(f'/Users/{self.nameUsers}\Downloads/soft.txt')
            print("success")
        else:
            print("File doesn't exists!")

        #Импорт основных методов передвижение окна windows и убарать windows элементы из виджета.
        self.pushClose.clicked.connect(self.importmainclass.CloseWindow)#кнопка завершение программы
        self.pushCollapse.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)#Сворачивание окна
        self.pushExit.clicked.connect(self.PushBack)#кнопка для выхода с аккаунта
        self.pushDownload.clicked.connect(self.download)


        #Достаем логин и email из бд для Profile
        Profile = coll.find_one({"_id": self.id_Profile})
        self.ProfileLogin = Profile.get("firstname")
        self.ProfileEmail = Profile.get("email")
        if Profile:
            print("login", self.ProfileLogin)
            print("Email", self.ProfileEmail)
        else:
            print("User not dound")

        #Перенос окна по используя frame в методах mouse press and event
        self.header_frame.move(0, 0)
        self.header_frame.show()
        #Работа с кнопкой профиль

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButtonProfile)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.pushButtonProfile.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.pushButtonProfile, b"size")
        self.animation.setDuration(600)

        self.is_expanded = False





    def on_button_clicked(self):
            if self.animation.state() == QAbstractAnimation.State.Stopped:
                if not self.is_expanded:
                    # Увеличение кнопки при нажатии
                    self.animation.setStartValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 51))
                    self.animation.setEndValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 115))
                    self.animation.start()

                    self.pushButtonProfile.setText("")
                    timer = QTimer()
                    timer.singleShot(500, self.AppealProfileLabelVisibility)
                    print('Увеличилась')
                    self.is_expanded = True
                else:
                    # Уменьшение кнопки при нажатии
                    self.animation.setStartValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 115))
                    self.animation.setEndValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 51))
                    self.animation.start()

                    # Добавление контента внутри кнопки
                    timer = QTimer()
                    timer.singleShot(0, self.AppealProfileLabelHide)

                    print('Уменьшилась')
                    self.is_expanded = False




    def AppealProfileLabelVisibility(self):
        self.label_ProfileLogo.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:white;')
        self.label_ProfileName.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:white;')
        self.label_ProfileEmail.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:white;')
        self.label_ProfileSub.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:white;')

        self.label_EnterProfileName.setText(self.ProfileLogin)
        self.label_EnterProfileEmail.setText(self.ProfileEmail)
        self.label_EnterProfileName.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:white;')
        self.label_EnterProfileEmail.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:white;')

    def AppealProfileLabelHide(self):
        self.pushButtonProfile.setText("Profile")

        self.label_ProfileLogo.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:transparent;')
        self.label_ProfileName.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:transparent;')
        self.label_ProfileEmail.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:transparent;')
        self.label_ProfileSub.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:transparent;')

        self.label_EnterProfileName.setText("")
        self.label_EnterProfileEmail.setText("")
        self.label_EnterProfileName.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:transparent;')
        self.label_EnterProfileEmail.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent;color:transparent;')

    def download(self):
        self.ui = Class.download.Download()
        self.ui.show()
        self.hide()

    def PushBack(self):
        self.ui = main.MainWindows()
        self.ui.show()
        self.hide()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and self.header_frame.underMouse():
            self.offset = event.pos()
        else:
            self.offset = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QMouseEvent) -> None:
        if self.offset is not None and event.buttons() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton and self.header_frame.underMouse():
            self.move(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos() - self.offset))
        else:
            self.offset = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно просто закрыть второе окно если проверка пройдена успешно, для этого (чтобы не передавать его как аргумент в инициализатор `AboutTheProgram`) нужно после проверки в функции `self.TransitionAboutTheProgram()` (как я понял она и отвечает за открытие окна `AboutTheProgram`) нужно закрыть текущее (с вводом логина) Выглядит как то так:

```
def TransitionAboutTheProgram(self):
        #self.hide()   p.s Зачем прятать? Окно функцию выполнило, нужно закрыть
        self.abouttheprogram = AboutTheProgram(self.id_Profile)
        self.abouttheprogram.show()
        self.close()  # < Закрываем окно с логином!
```

По идее должно работать. У себя проверил